# Not able to store data in table

Tags: php

not able to insert data in table I am using mysql database

```
$conn = new mysqli("localhost","username","password", "dbname");

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO mail_sent(mid, miid,status) VALUES (:mid, :miid,:status)");
$stmt->bind_param('dds',$mail_id, $inv_id, $mailStatus);//line 37
$stmt->bindParam(':mid', $mail_id);
$stmt->bindParam(':miid', $inv_id);
$stmt->bindParam(':status', $mailStatus);
$stmt->execute();
```

> Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\mail\toinvite.php on line 37

Comment: prepare() will then return false if the sql is not right according to db table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are confusing PDO with MySQLi. Only PDO have the syntax `:mid`, MySQL/MySQLi can't understand this. For prepared statements in MySQLi, you'll have to use `?` as placeholders.

```
if ($stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO mail_sent (mid, miid, status) VALUES (?, ?, ?)")) {
    $stmt->bind_param('iis', $mail_id, $inv_id, $mailStatus);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

As you can see, MySQLi handles all bindings in a single line, a little different than what PDO does. Also, your database has the IDs as ints, so I assigned them as integers in the `bind_param` too (you previously used doubles).

- `i` corresponding variable has type integer
- `d` corresponding variable has type double
- `s` corresponding variable has type string
- `b` corresponding variable is a blob and will be sent in packets

Reference:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php (MySQLi prepared statements)
- http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php (PDO prepared statements)

Comment: but it is executing 4 times??

Comment: Then you have a loop of sorts (`for`, `while`, `foreach`) wrapped around it (or load the script more times), because this code alone will only execute once.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do right after the prepare statement.

```
var_dump($stmt);
```

I am sure that the prepare statement is failing(i.e. returning FLASE). and if that fails you cannot call `bind_param()` on it.
There might be an mismatch in the column names you have in DB or the Table name

and are you sure `mid, miid` are double and not integers as you are using 'd' to bind the params.

Comment: showing  boolean false

Comment: yes so there is a problem with the prepare statement. Can you please add the Table definition as well for the table mail_sent

Comment: mail_sent(id bigint(20),mid bigint(20),miid bigint(20),add_date timestamp,STATUS varchar(20));

Comment: create table mail_mailid_invitation(
id bigint( 20 ) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
mid bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
miid  bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
status varchar(20) NOT NULL default 'fail',
add_date timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);

Comment: okay, please show me how do you assign the vaiables $mail_id & $inv_id. Try using $mail_id = 'some int value' and $inv_id = 'some int value' and also use 's' (as string param) instead of 'd' (double) in the bind_param call

Comment: so it should look like $stmt->bind_param('sss',$mail_id, $inv_id, $mailStatus); and $mail_id & $inv_id make it as string

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100832/discussion-between-saurabh-sinha-and-xrcwrn).